# Delegate different CSS animations to different child elements of a single parent

Tags: javascript, ajax, css-animations, fetch-api

Can I 'delegate' two different CSS @keyframe animations from one parent element to two different child elements, in the content of AJAX/Fetch API dynamically aded content?

For this code:

HTML

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child one'>Some text</div>
  <div class='child two'>Other text</div>
</div>
```

CSS (SASS)

```
.parent
  animation: BY 15s infinite alternate

@keyframes BY
  0%
    color: blue
  100%
    color: yellow
```

...text within both child elements '.one' and '.two' are affected by the delegated animation.

If these elements are reloaded dynamically, the animation keeps going across reloads, instead of restarting from 0% on every load.

But I need a different animation on '.one' than on '.two'. So if I apply the animations directly to the elements (as would be logical):

CSS (SASS)

```
.child.one
  animation: RG 15s infinite alternate

.child.two
  animation: GY 15s infinite alternate

@keyframes RG
  0%
    color: red
  100%
    color: green

@keyframes BY
  0%
    color: blue
  100%
    color: yellow
```

**...whenever I dynamically reload the elements the animation restarts at 0%.**

This codepen shows this behaviour:

https://codepen.io/plagasul/pen/WNerBvO

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may have to do with how objects are maintained in the DOM. Since `div class="fixed BY"` isn't being removed from the DOM, it's the same object that had the initial animation being performed on it so it's animation continues uninterrupted.

However since it's `innerHTML` is changing, what is happening is the internal DOM objects are being destroyed and the new contents are being created. It's upon being added to the DOM that the `class="RG"` animation starts thus creating this flash.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right. But binding the animation to the parent element solves this, as any dynamically created child elements inherit the animation from the parent at its current %, instead of restarting. As much is clear, BUT my problem is that I need different animations on different dynamically created elements, that are both children of this parent element.

Comment: So let me make sure I understand, you need an animation not only on the parent, but individual children (let's assume nth child for simplicity)? Or just on individual children?

Comment: I may be asking a XY question. I've rewritten my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495419/continuous-animation-across-dynamically-loaded-elements